# Password reset not redirecting to the template in Django

Tags: django, django-registration, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to override the default email to reset a password in Django rest-auth with an html template.

I'm trying to use:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password/reset/', auth_views.password_reset,
    {
        'html_email_template_name':'registration/password_reset_email_html.html',
    }, 
    name="password_reset"),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

The email is successfully sent, but with the default template.
I can override this by adding a custom template file `registration/password_reset_email.html`, but then the email is only sent as plain text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

We also encounter this before, and we used the EmailMultiAlternatives from django.core.mail to send an html email.

Here's a sample code:

```
def custom_send_mail(to_email,subject,html_email_template_name=None,context=None,from_email = None):
# Email subject *must not* contain newlines
subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, subject, from_email, [to_email])
#html_email_template_name = "registration/password_reset_confirm_html_email.html"
if html_email_template_name is not None:
    html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name,context)
    email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

email_message.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^password/reset/$',auth_views.password_reset,{'template_name':'registration/password_reset_email_html.html'},name='reset_password'),
```

Follow the above urlpattern and it may help.
Also refer this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html